# using reduce local_train in custom_federated_algorithms_2 tutorial

Tags: tensorflow-federated

the [custom_federated_algorithms_2 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2) presents a local_train function using `tff.federated_computation`.

There a comment saying "while we could have implemented this logic entirely in TensorFlow, relying on `tf.data.Dataset.reduce`...":

regarding this comment:

1. I didn't manage to actually convert the code to using `tf.data.Dataset.reduce` seems non-trivial and the debug comments really don't help
2. I wonder what is the motivation of using federated_computation in cases like this, I looked all over the guides and real did find an explanation for what is going on here and when should we use it.

thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Addressing these two in order:

1. It may not be trivial to adapt the code given directly to use `tf.data.Dataset.reduce`; that comment is intended to call out that the logic expressed here is also expressible using the dataset-reduce primitive, as effectively it only represents a local reduction, there are no communications across placements happening here.
2. There are at least two distinct purposes of this demonstration. One is to show that TFF as a language does not necessarily rely on the in-graph looping constructs of TensorFlow; another is to demonstrate the ability to "capture" values using the federated computation decorator. This could be used to natively capture something like learning rate decay in TFF, by evaluating a function of the round number and closing over it in the manner above, though there are other ways to implement similar functionality, as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/optimization/shared/fed_avg_schedule.py) for example.

I personally find this pattern a little confusing; reading into the question behind the question a little, I agree that it is confusing to use a `federated_computation` decorator where there is no communication happening. When writing TFF, I generally express *all* my local computation in TensorFlow proper (usually in a functional manner), and let TFF handle the communication only. The purpose of the second tutorial is to show that TFF proper is actually much more flexible than indicated by restricting oneself to using the pattern just described.